# Why doesn't the graph of $x^2-\cos x$ look wiggly?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, curves

When I use Desmos to draw the graph of the function $f$ defined by $f(x):=x^2-\cos x$, the graph looks very similar to a quadratic function. Unlike the graph of, say, $x-\cos x$, it does not have any wiggles/waves. I would expect the $\cos x$ term in $f(x)$ to cause there to be some wiggles, but this appears not to be the case. Why is this? I assume it has something to do with $x^2$ growing much faster than $\cos x$ ever does. Or perhaps it's because $f$ is everywhere convex, so always keeps growing steeply upwards when $x$ is positive.

I have also notices that the graphs of $x^2-\cos(kx)$ are wiggly for $k\ge3$, but not for $k=1,2$.

Can anyone shed any more light on why $x^2-\cos x$ doesn't have any wiggles?

Comment: Second derivative $2+\cos x>0$

Comment: The second part of your question can also be addressed with the 2nd derivative. There is such thing called chain rule and that rule makes sure the 2nd derivative is no longer sign observant. (i.e. for larger k the 2nd derivative will change signs)

Comment: Well, it depends on what you mean by "wiggles": it *does* wiggle around the graph of $y=x^2$ so if you imagine riding along the parabola, a car on your curve would sometimes be to your left and then to your right and then to your left again and so on, but admittedly that's a subtler wiggle than the second derivative sloshing positive and negative.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that the second derivative is always positive:
$$f(x)=x^2-\cos(x)\implies f''(x)=2+\cos(x)\geq 1>0$$
and therefore the function $f$ is strictly convex (and it doesn't have any wiggles). 
More generally,
$$f_k(x)=x^2-\cos(kx)\implies f_k''(x)=2+k^2\cos(kx)$$ 
and $f_k''$ changes its sign for $k^2>2$.